# How to count Time in MySQL group by ID?

Tags: mysql

How to count time in MySQL? so I have table like down below:

```
id | time     |
01 | 00:36:00 |
01 | 01:00:00 |
02 | 00:30:00 |
```

and I need the time to be count this group by id like this:

```
id | time     |
01 | 01:36:00 |
02 | 00:30:00 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the `sum`

```
SELECT 
RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR(COALESCE (SUM(
        datediff(second,
                cast('1900-01-01' as datetime),
                cast(time as datetime)
               )/3600.0), 0) / 60) AS VARCHAR (8)), 2)
               + ':' +
               RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR(COALESCE (SUM(
        datediff(second,
                cast('1900-01-01' as datetime),
                cast(time as datetime)
               )/3600.0), 0) % 60) AS VARCHAR (2)), 2) + ':' + 
                RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR((SUM(
        datediff(second,
                cast('1900-01-01' as datetime),
                cast(time as datetime)
               )/3600.0)* 60) % 60) AS VARCHAR (2)), 2)
             as DecimalHours
, ID
FROM #t 
group by ID
```

What I did was convert your time first into decimal (so we can perform a `SUM`) then formatted the sum to a time format.

Comment: i just need to sum Time, how to do it?

Comment: this returns the sum of time.. have you tried to run it? @devian

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your time to second, then sum up and reformat it.

```
SELECT 
   id, 
   CONCAT(
      LPAD(FLOOR(seconds / 3600), 2, '0'), ':',         -- hour
      LPAD(FLOOR((seconds % 3600) / 60), 2, '0'), ':',  -- minute
      LPAD(seconds % 60, 2, '0')) as time               -- second
FROM 
    (SELECT id, 
          SUM(CAST(SUBSTRING(time, 1, 2) AS UNSIGNED) * 3600
          + CAST(SUBSTRING(time, 4, 2) AS UNSIGNED) * 60
          + CAST(SUBSTRING(time, 7, 2) AS UNSIGNED)) AS seconds
    FROM <your table name>
    GROUP BY id) AS summary
```

You could reference a demo here http://rextester.com/INOI78655